# Why the Bottom Sheet is on the main screen?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app with Bottom Sheet. But when I run the app, the Bottom Sheet shows in main screen. It means, the Bottom Sheet appears in the main screen without clicking on the Button. An image has been attested below for clear understanding. [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x2UP.png)

This is the MainActivity.java class:

```
package com.example.qurdadzze.b;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
NestedScrollView bottomsheet;
BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    bottomsheet = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet);
    behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomsheet);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(behavior.getState()==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            else
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            behavior.setPeekHeight(0);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.qurdadzze.b.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="show bottom sheet"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#99cc99"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="it is me Bottom Sheet"/>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set peekheight of Bottomsheet.

**android.support.design:behavior_peekHeight The height of the bottom sheet when it is collapsed.**

Try using below code in your NestedScrollView:

```
app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
```

For more details check below link:
http://www.truiton.com/2016/07/android-bottom-sheet-example/